# DisabledException gets converted to InsufficientAuthenticationException by spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have override the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to return my custom error response. Inside an implementation of `UserDetailsService` I am passing the `enabled` field of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` as false. So each user is disabled (to test this).
But instead of getting `DisabledException` I always get `InsufficientAuthenticationException : Full authentication is required to access this resource`.

So I debugged more and found that `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider#authenticate` is throwing the right exception (`DisabledException`) but at some place it is getting converted to `InsufficientAuthenticationException`

SecurityConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.restapi.security"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final JwtConfigProperties jwtConfigProperties;
    private final Environment environment;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, JwtConfigProperties jwtConfigProperties, Environment environment) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtConfigProperties = jwtConfigProperties;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final JwtAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfigProperties, environment);
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl(URN_AUTH + URN_LOGIN);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"** private **")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "**public routes here**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), jwtConfigProperties))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().formLogin().disable().rememberMe().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
        ;
    }
}
```

RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

```
@Component(value = "restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx)
            throws IOException {
        String errorMessage;
        ErrorCode errorCode;

       // the authEx is always of type InsufficientAuthenticationException

        if (authEx.getClass().equals(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
            errorMessage = "Incorrect username or password";
            errorCode = ErrorCode.UN_AUTHORIZED;
        } else if (authEx.getClass().equals(DisabledException.class)) {
            errorMessage = "Account verification pending, kindly verify your email address. An email has already been sent to your registered email address. If you have trouble finding it, kindly check the spam folder as well.";
            errorCode = ErrorCode.DISABLED;
        } else {
            errorMessage = authEx.getMessage();
            errorCode = ErrorCode.UN_AUTHORIZED;
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ApiErrorDto apiErrorDto = new ApiErrorDto();
        apiErrorDto.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        apiErrorDto.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        apiErrorDto.setCode(errorCode.value());
        apiErrorDto.setType(errorCode.getReasonPhrase());
        apiErrorDto.setError(authEx.getClass().getSimpleName());
        apiErrorDto.setMessage(errorMessage);
        apiErrorDto.setPath(request.getRequestURI());

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(apiErrorDto)));
        writer.flush();

    }

}
```

UserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public MyUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("No account found for " + username));

        return buildAuthenticatedUser(user);
    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User buildAuthenticatedUser(User user) {
        String username = user.getEmail();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String uniqueId = user.getUniqueId();
        int userId = user.getUserId();
        boolean enabled = false; //hardcoded for now

        CurrentUser authenticatedUser = new CurrentUser(username, password, enabled, true, true, true, Collections.emptyList());
        authenticatedUser.setUniqueId(uniqueId);
        authenticatedUser.setUserId(userId);

        return authenticatedUser;
    }

}


////

@Getter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class CurrentUser extends User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9189146656953053184L;

    private Integer userId;
    private String uniqueId;

    protected CurrentUser(String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I debug it more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint` works well with Basic authentication. But if we write a custom  authentication filter we need to handle this unsuccessful login in that filter itself. In my case I am extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` so here is my implementation for unsuccessful authentication.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final JwtConfigProperties jwtConfigProperties;
    private final Environment environment;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, JwtConfigProperties jwtConfigProperties, Environment environment) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.jwtConfigProperties = jwtConfigProperties;
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        //logic
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authEx) throws IOException {
        String errorMessage;
        ErrorCode errorCode;
        int httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value();
        if (authEx.getClass().equals(BadCredentialsException.class)) {
            errorMessage = "Incorrect username or password";
            errorCode = ErrorCode.UN_AUTHORIZED;
        } else if (authEx.getClass().equals(DisabledException.class)) {
            errorMessage = "Account verification pending, kindly verify your email address. An email has already been sent to your registered email address. If you have trouble finding it, kindly check the spam folder as well.";
            errorCode = ErrorCode.DISABLED;
            httpStatus = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value();
        } else {
            errorMessage = authEx.getMessage();
            errorCode = ErrorCode.UN_AUTHORIZED;
        }

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ApiErrorDto apiErrorDto = new ApiErrorDto();
        apiErrorDto.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        apiErrorDto.setStatus(httpStatus);
        apiErrorDto.setCode(errorCode.value());
        apiErrorDto.setType(errorCode.getReasonPhrase());
        apiErrorDto.setError(authEx.getClass().getSimpleName());
        apiErrorDto.setMessage(errorMessage);
        apiErrorDto.setPath(request.getRequestURI());

        response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        writer.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(apiErrorDto)));
        writer.flush();
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //logic
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, auth);
    }


    @Setter
    @Getter
    private static class LoginCredentials {
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }

}
```

This now throw the actual exception thrown inside `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`.

Hope it would help someone.